# Macro for removing row starting with other than "BE" in the column

Tags: vba, excel

I have written basic Excel macro for filtering data which kinda worked OK. But I struggle with deleting rows, if column F does not start with "BE". In column F there are ISINs for commercial papers and first two letter are country code, followed by few numbers. There is also header. 
If you are interested, here is the procedure for what the macro should do:

1. Delete row 1 and 2
2. Sort by Pay date (PD): (oldest to newest)
3. Withhold the events (rows) with specific pay date (column L)
4. Withhold in column H everything that are not these:

   - Shares
   - Shares limited Partnership
   - Shares Fractions
   - Funds
   - Certificates ADR
   - Certificates
   - Investment funds BE dividend
   - Investment funds BE capitalization
   - Pre-emptive right
   - Mortage certificates
5. Sort by ISIN code: A to Z (column F)
6. Withhold everything else than "BE" in column F

My current code looks like this.

```
Sub Paycheck()

'Delete first two rows
        Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
        Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

' Restore screen updating and events
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

' DELETES ALL ROWS FROM A2 DOWNWARDS WITH THE WORDs IN COLUMN H
' USE THIS TO CLEAR CONTENTS BUT NOT DELETE ROW "Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents"

     Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "SHARES" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Shares limited Partnership" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Shares Fractions" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Funds" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Certificates ADR" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Certificates" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Investment funds BE dividend" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Investment funds BE capitalization" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Pre-emptive right" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Mortgage certificates" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If

' Deleting other than BE

        If (Mid(cell(i, "F").Value, 0, 2) <> "BE") Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i

' This will clear dates which are not today

   Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = Last To 2 Step -1
   If (Cells(i, "L").Value) < Date Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
   Next i

   Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = Last To 2 Step -1
   If (Cells(i, "L").Value) > Date Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
   Next i

'Order the table ascending

   Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Events").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Events").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
        ("F:F"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Events").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter


End Sub
```

As you can see approx in middle of the code, I tried to use basic "if" function with "mid". But I think I got it wrong (because it does not work). I even tried some other codes I have found (I am beginner and I am looking around internet for solutions).
What I have tried or found and did not work. For example:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Events")

    lastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("F1:F" & lastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*BE*"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
```

I also found some loop code, which also did not worked (and took a lot of time, we are talking about thousands of rows I need to filter). Currently I am in situation when even the code that worked before, does not work anymore (because I somewhere fucked up) so I would really like your advice, how to make this work according to the procedure mentioned above.
I would be very grateful!
Thank you for your time

Comment: Replace you mid with mid(cell(i, "F").Value,instr(1,cell(i, "F").Value,"BE"),2)

Comment: in this line `If (Mid(cell(i, "F").Value, 0, 2) <> "BE") Then` replace `cell` with `Cells`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..this code simple skip the row which has value start with **BE** in **Column F**

Note: not tested

```
         Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        ' If Column F values starts with BE then skip the row
            If Cells(i, "F").Value = "BE*" Then
                GoTo nextline:
            End If


            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "SHARES" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Shares limited Partnership" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Shares Fractions" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Funds" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Certificates ADR" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Certificates" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Investment funds BE dividend" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Investment funds BE capitalization" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Pre-emptive right" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            If (Cells(i, "H").Value) <> "Mortgage certificates" Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If



    nextline:
            Next i

    ' This will clear dates which are not today

       Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "F").Value = "BE*" Then
            GoTo nextline1:
        End If
       If (Cells(i, "L").Value) < Date Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                End If
    nextline1:
       Next i

       Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "F").Value = "BE*" Then
            GoTo nextline2:
        End If

        If (Cells(i, "L").Value) > Date Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    nextline2:
       Next i
```